# adjusting font size of all captions with prefered font size

Tags: captions, fontsize

I would like to change the font size of all captions in my thesis. The solutions I saw, were referring to use Caption package and font=footnotesize. However, this option is not suitable for me while I want to have the font exactly adjusted. As an example, the font size of the text is 11pt and I want the captions to be either 10pt or 9pt.

Comment: If 11pt is the normal text font size, then `\small` is 10pt and `\footnotesize` is 9pt.

Comment: I could not apply small to every captions. However, what Ulrike suggested works. Thanks for your comment. @campa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a special size with `\DeclareCaptionFont`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{specialsize}{\fontsize{8.3pt}{10pt}\selectfont}
\begin{document}

\captionof{figure}{Normal size}

\captionsetup{font=specialsize}
\captionof{figure}{Special size}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works. Thanks Ulrike.

Answer (score 0):

```
\usepackage[%
            font=small,
        %   labelfont={bf,sf}
%           tablename=Tableau,
%           format=hang,
%           labelsep=period,
%           justification=centerlast,
            textfont=rm
            ]
            {caption}

\captionsetup{labelfont={scriptsize,bf,sf}}
```